# Django root path not found after adding handler404

Tags: django

I added a handler404 to my project and it immediately broke the root path and the 404 page is shown.
I wonder how I need to change my urls.py to make it work correctly with i18n_patterns. I would appreciate any advice on the issue.

The URLs with the language prefix work fine.

```
mysite.com         404  why????
mysite.com/en/     OK
mysite.com/fr/     OK
mysite.com/gffg    404
```

Here's the urls.py of my project.

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    
    #apps
    path('', include('apps.webapp.urls')),
    path('user/', include('apps.userapp.urls')),
    path('client-area/', include('apps.accountapp.urls')),
    
    #additional paths
    path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
         name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
) +  [ 
    path("robots.txt", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="web/robots.txt", content_type="text/plain"),),
    ]

handler404 =  'apps.webapp.views.handler404'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i18n_patterns` has a keyword argument `prefix_default_language` whose default is `True`. According to the documentation it:

> Setting **prefix_default_language** to **False** removes the prefix
> from the default language
> ([**LANGUAGE_CODE**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-LANGUAGE_CODE)).
> This can be useful when adding translations to existing site so that
> the current URLs won’t change.

You haven't set this to `False` in your code so you end up not having a pattern that would match `mysite.com`. Add the keyword argument to the function call so that you don't need the prefix for the default language:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...,
    prefix_default_language=False,
)
```

Comment: I don't want to lose the prefix of the default language from URLs. I have a VueJS widget that retrieves the current language from the path. Do you think there is other solution?

Comment: Just removing this line helped to resolve the issue.

handler404 =  'apps.webapp.views.handler404'

Answer (score 0):

I created custom error view to handle this issue

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings

def handler_error_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    for lang_code, _ in settings.LANGUAGES:
        if request.path.startswith('/'+lang_code):
            return render(request, 'generals/your_error_template.html')
    return redirect('/'+settings.LANGUAGE_CODE+request.path)
```